# How To Add Color To SharePoint List Column Background?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, column, jslink

I have a requirement to make the background of a column in a SharePoint list colored (e.g. green).

I have seen posts on CSR, JSLink, Conditional Formatting, etc. & all of these articles target list items, and individual list data but not full column background color.

Is there a way to color a full column background?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is to hard code the columnnumber in CSS:

```
.ms-listviewtable thead tr th:nth-child(5),
.ms-listviewtable tbody tr td:nth-child(5){
    background:pink;
}
```